# Java package structure

Tags: java, package

As a best-practice, is it ok for interfaces / classes in higher level packages to depend on interfaces / classes in lower level packages?

e.g.

can `com.company.core.SomeClass` depend on `com.company.core.apackage.AnotherClass`

Or should the dependencies flow the other way? I am trying to eliminate cycles between packages.

Answer (score 2):

Such dependencies are common even in the Java API itself.

Look at: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/renderable/package-use.html

You can see that classes in `java.awt` *use* classes in `java.awt.image.renderable`.

(ADDENDUM) Bottom line: Both directions are used in practice.  One is not, IMHO, necessarily better than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a user of a package might be interested in `com.company.functionality.MainUse`, which is implemented using `com.company.functionality.implementationdetail.FiddleWithStuff`, so I'd say you have to accept dependencies in that direction.

But the other direction is probably necessary as well, as implementation detail classes may need to implement interfaces that is part of the interface to the functionality.

So, unfortunatley, I think a strict directionality like that isn't a workable way to avoid cycles.

Answer (score 2):

They usually flow the other way. com.mycompany.myproduct.Widget is an interface, and com.mycompany.myproduct.fancy.Button implements it.

There are however big exceptions to this general rule, and there is no reasons why it should be a rule.

Packages themselves are simply folders, except for primitive access rules on methods and fields.

What is far more important are dependencies between bundles, that is (in their basic form) jars. Having jar A depend on jar B depending on jar C depending again on jar A is a real problem. If you have the same circle between packages in the same jar, it can cause frustration in people who read or debug your code, or in elitists reading it, but is not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you're using the so-called **top-down approach**, a package depends on its subpackages but not vice versa.

The bottom-up approach would be the other way around, a package would depend on its parent packages but not vice versa.

Either way is fine as long as you are able to maintain consistency, but the **top-down approach** is easier and more common.

Comment: But that would mean that we can't have some public interfaces and factories in a top-level package and the private implementation in some lower level package, which seems quite usual.

Comment: @ivo By "maintain consistency", do you mean throughout the project or just for that one package with its subpackages?